# Programs to monitor CentOS servers and workstations?

Tags: networking, centos, redhat, monitoring, hardware

Are there programs / solutions that would allow me to monitor the hardware, software, issues, performance, networking and I/O of approximately 100 CentOS/Rhel servers and workstations?

Google finds only Windows based programs, or programs for network/performance monitoring, but not hardware/software.

Comment: Something like Nagios might work for you. There's a list of tools [here](https://www.ubuntupit.com/most-comprehensive-list-of-linux-monitoring-tools-for-sysadmin/), but most are single server tools.

Comment: Thanks for the editing and recommendation, @Tim: I'll try `Nagios XI` out.

Comment: Any other suggestions besides `Nagios`, @Tim? I have issues with Nagios: first, it recommends installation on pristine machines - which is unacceptable. When I tried to install it on an already installed machine, it could not start MariaDB, and when I tried to create an account on Nagios support site, I was refused (Because "'I am a well-known spammer.' or 'My ISP is well-known for a lot of spamming customers and is not fighting against spammers enough.'")

Comment: Google "software like Nagios". I can't recommend anything really, though I've played with PTRG (Windows) a little and it's pretty awesome, much much easier than Nagios

Comment: Xymon, alas know as hobbit monitor in the past could do a part of the job. Only for the hardware I'am not sure, but you could check if you can add SNMP trap to monitor it.

Answer (score 0):

you should use Munin. You will need Munin server and Munin-nodes in every machine you need to monitor, in addition you can install custom plugins for 3rd party software.